# Need help with regular expression matching

Tags: regex, perl

Given:

```
$num = "3";

$num_list = "30 3 42 54";
```

How can I match the "3" and not the "30"? The number order will always be changing.

I tried:

```
if ($num_list =~ /(\s?$num\s+/)
```

Unfortunately it matches the "3" in "30". Not sure how to fix it. I know it's because of the `?` means 0 or 1.

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Try using word boundaries:

```
/\b$num\b/
```

`\b` will either match start or end of string or any boundary between word character and  non-word character (i.e. between `[0-9a-zA-Z_]` and not `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`).

Comment: While the solution is acceptable here, your explanation is wrong. `/!\b!/` will never match despite your claims that it should match `!#!`. Furthermore, there are many more word characters than those.

Comment: `\b` is equivalent to `(?:(?<!\w)(?=\w)|(?<!\W)(?=\W))`

Answer (score 2):

A solution that's great if you're going to check if a lot of numbers are in $num_list:

```
my $pat = join '|', map quotemeta, split " ", $num_list;
my $re = qr/^(?:$pat)\z/;

$num =~ $re
```

A solution that's great if you're going to check if a lot of numbers are in $num_list:

```
my %num_list = map { $_ => 1 } split " ", $num_list;

$num_list{$num}
```

A solution that doesn't require regexp (great for SQL):

```
index(" $num_list ", " $num ") >= 0
```

Simple solutions:

```
" $num_list " =~ / $num /

$num_list =~ /(?<!\S)$num(?!\S)/

$num_list =~ /\b$num\b/

grep { $_ == $num } split " ", $num_list
```

Answer (score 1):

How about not using regexps at all?

```
 $num = 3;
 @num_list = qw[30 3 42 54];
 if (grep { $_ == $num } @num_list) {
    ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, Perl uses the same regex as preg_match in PHP
Then you can try the following:

```
/(?<=^|\s)($num)(?=$|\s)/
```

I should have a start or whitespace before the 3, and an end or whitespace afterwards

Comment: `/(?<=^|\s)($num)(?=$|\s)/` is simpler as `/(?<!\S)($num)(?!\S)/`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
$num_list = "30 3 42 54";
$num = "3";
@arr = explode(" ", $num_list);

if (scalar grep {$_ eq $num} @num_list) {
    print "Zuko!\n";
}
```

Comment: `explode(" ", $num_list)` exists as `split(" ", $num_list)`